# How to draw border for whole pdf pages using iText library 5.5.2

Tags: android, pdf, border, itext

As in title mentioned, how to draw border with "RED" color , width-stroke 5 for all generated pdf pages using iText library. I've tried some codes but got no result.

(1)

```
                    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
                    table.setWidthPercentage(99);
                    table.setLockedWidth(true);

                    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
                    cell.setFixedHeight(PageSize.A4.getHeight());


                    document.add(table);
```

(2)

```
                    PdfContentByte content = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fout).getDirectContent();
                    Rectangle pageRect = document.getPageSize();

                    pageRect.setLeft(pageRect.getLeft() + 10);
                    pageRect.setRight(pageRect.getRight() - 10);
                    pageRect.setTop(pageRect.getTop() - 10);
                    pageRect.setBottom(pageRect.getBottom() +10);

                    content.setColorStroke( BaseColor.BLUE);
                    content.rectangle(pageRect.getLeft(), pageRect.getBottom(), pageRect.getWidth(), pageRect.getHeight());
                    content.setLineWidth(10);
                    content.stroke();
                    content.fillStroke();
```

Those methods give me no result, Thanks!

---

### Edit

I've changed my methods also thanks to Bruno Lowagie for his respond. the example worked like a charm but i couldn't fit it into my code.

Here's my code: By pressing a button, PDF file will generate at specif address. I'll add more content later but now let's stick to generating pdf file(s).

```
   SaveToSD = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SaveToMemoryCard_xml);
    SaveToSD.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View sssdd)
        {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/ConcreteProject";
            File dir = new File(path);
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();
            Log.d("PDFCreator", "PDF Path: " + path);

            // Incremental Process of Creating File(s).
            String pdfName = "SDG_Created_pdf.pdf";
            int num = 0;
            File file = new File(dir, pdfName);
            while (file.exists()) {
                num++;
                pdfName = "SDG_Created_pdf" + num + ".pdf";
                file = new File(dir, pdfName);
            }


            try {

                new ConAccept_Result().createPdf(pdfName);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }//End Of onClick(View sssdd).
    });
```

And Here is method/class definitions:

```
public class RedBorder extends PdfPageEventHelper {
    @Override
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
        Rectangle rect = document.getPageSize();
        rect.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX); // left, right, top, bottom border
        rect.setBorderWidth(5); // a width of 5 user units
        rect.setBorderColor(BaseColor.RED); // a red border
        rect.setUseVariableBorders(true); // the full width will be visible
        canvas.rectangle(rect);
    }
}

public void createPdf(String stringfile) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    // step 1
    com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();

    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(stringfile));
    RedBorder event = new RedBorder();
    writer.setPageEvent(event);
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4

    Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Lovin' iText - Lovin' iText");
    chunk.setTextRenderMode(PdfContentByte.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_FILL_STROKE, 0.3f, BaseColor.CYAN);
    document.add(chunk);

    // step 5
    document.close();
}
```

After running da app a folder as i named created but there is no PDF file !

Thanks a lot..

Comment: I don't know whether that causes problems here, but strictly speaking that 'content.setLineWidth(10);' is invalid at that point: as soon as you start constructing a path ('content.rectangle(...)' in your case), you may only add path segments or finish the path using a stroking, filling, clipping, or ignoring operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading your question, it seems obvious that you need a page event. Your attempts will add a border only once whereas you probably want to add a border to each page.

Please take a look at the [PageBorder](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/events/PageBorder) example. In this example, you'll find an implementation of the `PageEvents` interface named `RedBorder`:

```
public class RedBorder extends PdfPageEventHelper {
    @Override
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
        Rectangle rect = document.getPageSize();
        rect.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX); // left, right, top, bottom border
        rect.setBorderWidth(5); // a width of 5 user units
        rect.setBorderColor(BaseColor.RED); // a red border
        rect.setUseVariableBorders(true); // the full width will be visible
        canvas.rectangle(rect);
    }
}
```

The `onEndPage()` method is triggered automatically, every time a page ends (**do not** use the`onStartPage()` method to add content).

In the implementation of this method, we ask the `document` object for its current page size. Note that the `document` instance passed to the event is of type `PdfDocument`. It is **not** the same document as used in the `createPdf()` method.

We adapt the rectangle to our needs. We set the border to `BOX` meaning we want to add a border to the left, right, top and bottom. We define the width of the border (in this case 5 user units) and we define the color.

If you would stop there, a rectangle with a border of 5 user units would be drawn, but you would only see lines of 2.5 user units because the other half of the 5 user units would be *outside the visible area* of the page.

You can avoid this by using a width of 10 user units, or by setting the *variable borders* flag to `true`.

Now all we have to do is to pass the `rect` object to the `rectangle()` method. This method is different from the method with the same name you have used in the sense that it also strokes the rectangle.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was useful and more than that the PageExample you've linked.

Answer (score 0):

In onClick part of SaveToSD there are some changes. Change these:

```
 String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/ConcreteProject";
        File dir = new File(path);
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();
        Log.d("PDFCreator", "PDF Path: " + path);

        // Incremental Process of Creating File(s).
        String pdfName = "SDG_Created_pdf.pdf";
        int num = 0;
        File file = new File(dir, pdfName);
        while (file.exists()) {
            num++;
            pdfName = "SDG_Created_pdf" + num + ".pdf";
            file = new File(dir, pdfName);
        }
        try {
            new ConAccept_Result().createPdf(pdfName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

With this:

```
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/ConcreteProject";
            File dir = new File(path);
            if(!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();

            //Incremental
            String NameWithCounter = "/ConcreteProject/myPDFfile_1.pdf";
            String DEST = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+NameWithCounter;
            //int FileCounter = 1;
            File real_file = new File(DEST);
            while(real_file.exists()){
                FileCounter++;
                NameWithCounter = "/ConcreteProject/myPDFfile_"+FileCounter+".pdf";
                DEST = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+NameWithCounter;
                real_file = new File(DEST);
            }

            try {
                createPdf(DEST);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

So when user press Save to Memory, PDF files will generated. For example if user pressed 4 times there will be 4 different PDF file with increment file name.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same this way..

```
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, bout);
document.open();
......
//read the PDF however you want to PDFReader testPdf 

for (int page = 0; page < noOfPages; ) {
    PdfImportedPage importedPage = copy.getImportedPage(testPdf, ++page);
    PageStamp pageStamp = copy.createPageStamp(importedPage);
    addHilitePageBlock(pageStamp);
    copy.addPage(importedPage);
}
copy.freeReader(testPdf);
testPdf.close();
......



public void addPageBlock(PageStamp stamp) throws IOException {
    PdfContentByte canvas = stamp.getOverContent();
    drawRectangle(canvas, PageSize.A5.getWidth(), PageSize.A5.getHeight());
    stamp.alterContents();
}
public void drawRectangle(PdfContentByte content, float width, float height) {
    content.saveState();
    PdfGState state = new PdfGState();
    state.setFillOpacity(0.0f);
    content.setGState(state);
    content.setColorStroke(BaseColor.RED);
    content.setLineWidth(6);
    content.rectangle(17, 17, width + 155, height+ 145);
    content.fillStroke();
    content.restoreState();
}
```