# How to apply borders to PDF page?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, pdf

```
public void pdf()
{
    iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet styles = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
    table.TotalWidth = 400f;
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A2, 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);

    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
    document.Open();
    PdfContentByte content = writer.DirectContent;
    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rectangle = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(document.PageSize);
    rectangle.Left += document.LeftMargin;
    rectangle.Right -= document.RightMargin;
    rectangle.Top -= document.TopMargin;
    rectangle.Bottom += document.BottomMargin;

    content.SetColorStroke(iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLUE);
    content.Rectangle(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Bottom, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
    content.Stroke();            

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Invoice.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

    divM.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(stringWriter.ToString());
  //  Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 7f, 7f, 7f, 0f);

    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(document);
    htmlparser.SetStyleSheet(styles);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
    document.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    document.Close();
    Response.Write(document);
    Response.End();


}
```

Here i am not getting any borders in pdf page..and i tried another way.

```
    styles.LoadStyle("pdf", "border", "1");
```

If i applied this line,i got every line with border

```
     styles.LoadStyle("pdf", "border-top", "1");
     styles.LoadStyle("pdf", "border-bottom", "1");
     styles.LoadStyle("pdf", "border-left", "1");
     styles.LoadStyle("pdf", "border-right", "1");
     styles.LoadStyle("pdf", "size", "4");
```

If i applied this code ,then i am not getting any border ..
How can i add page borders in pdf page using Itextsharp.dll file in asp.net

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw border for whole pdf pages using iText library 5.5.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749828/how-to-draw-border-for-whole-pdf-pages-using-itext-library-5-5-2)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, if it helps you

```
  <form id="form2" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="btnReportForPDF" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="GenerateReportForPDF" />
   </form>
```

Namespace:-

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
```

Code for your reference:

```
protected void GenerateReportForPDF(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
    Font NormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK);
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
        Phrase phrase = null;
        PdfPCell cell = null;
        PdfPTable table = null;

        document.Open();

        //Header Table
        table = new PdfPTable(1);
        table.TotalWidth = 400f;
        table.LockedWidth = true;
        table.SetWidths(new float[] { 1f });

        //Company Name and Address
        phrase = new Phrase();
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Microsoft Northwind Traders Company\n\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 16, Font.BOLD, Color.RED)));
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("107, Park site,\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Salt Lake Road,\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Seattle, USA", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        cell = PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT);
        cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_TOP;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        document.Add(table);

        table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        table.SetWidths(new float[] { 0.3f, 1f });
        table.SpacingBefore = 20f;

        //Employee Details
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase("Employee Record", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.UNDERLINE, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        table.AddCell(cell);
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 30f;
        table.AddCell(cell);//cell will get added in a table.

        table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.SetWidths(new float[] { 0.5f, 2f });
        table.TotalWidth = 340f;
        table.LockedWidth = true;
        table.SpacingBefore = 20f;
        table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

        phrase = new Phrase();
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Title\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)));
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("(Moderator)", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)));
        cell = PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT);
        cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(" "), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Employee Id
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Employee code:", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("0001", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);


        //Address
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Address:", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk("507 - 20th Ave. E.\nApt. 2A\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Seattle\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("WA USA 98122", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Date of Birth
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Date of Birth:", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("17 MARCH", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);
        document.Add(table);

        //Add border to page
        PdfContentByte content = writer.DirectContent;
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(document.PageSize);
        rectangle.Left += document.LeftMargin;
        rectangle.Right -= document.RightMargin;
        rectangle.Top -= document.TopMargin;
        rectangle.Bottom += document.BottomMargin;
        content.SetColorStroke(Color.BLACK);
        content.Rectangle(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Bottom, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
        content.Stroke();

        document.Close();
        byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        memoryStream.Close();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Employee.pdf");
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.End();
        Response.Close();
    }
}

private static PdfPCell PhraseCell(Phrase phrase, int align)
{
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(phrase);
    cell.BorderColor = Color.WHITE;
    cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_TOP;
    cell.HorizontalAlignment = align;
    cell.PaddingBottom = 2f;
    cell.PaddingTop = 0f;
    return cell;
}
```